# Swiper sliders with set width broke - 25.8.2021

Tags: html, css, slider, swiper.js

Has anybody else experienced broken sliders today? All my sliders that have set width are broken(take the full width). BTW I'm using their CDN in code

Comment: Welcome! Could you add some minimal reproducible code for your sliders? In that way it's easier for us to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer below was right! They changed the class of the container from "swiper-container" to just "swiper" and that's what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they recently pushed an update to v7.0. I changed my CDN links to:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

as per their updated ["Getting started"](https://swiperjs.com/get-started) instructions, and the overflow-x problem was fixed.